# Exporting Maya Animation and Bones to .Json

Tags: animation, three.js, maya

Iv'e tried every setting of so many exporters to get this to work,  the blacktowers modified exporter for three.js, Inka3d, clara.io and online converters, and trying opening the FBX with animation into blender to no avil.

The  FBX has animation and plays on websites such as clara.io and inside of Maya / 3DS Max, however when exporting the .json or .js  it doesn't work inside the online editor or offline editors.

Is there any other way to get Animations with skinned bones / joints from Maya to .js / .json that will work inside of Three.Js?

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is inaccurate. It is possible (and, indeed, common) to export animations and bones to three.js-friendly JSON files, from all the major 3d formats (FBX, DAE, etc.). The most robust and foolproof way seems to be through the JSON exporter in Blender - sometimes it still requires some fidgeting with, but the pipeline is mostly functional in 99% percent of the cases I've seen.

Currently (Jan '16) there is no need to use the blacktower exporter; [the standard JSON exporter for Blender](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender) works just fine.

[This](http://blog.romanliutikov.com/post/60461559240/rigging-and-skeletal-animation-in-threejs) is a good tutorial, although current practices (at least my own) differ slightly and you may have to play with various exporter options to make it work for you. If you're still running into problems, please post a clearer description of your specific issue and I'll try to help you get it working.

Comment: The tutorial link you provided is broken.

Comment: not entirely surprising as it's been over a year and a half since I wrote it.
A more important update is that the industry is slowly but surely moving to a newer format called glTF2 (and, formerly, glTF). I'd strongly encourage researching it as in my experience it offers the most robust pipeline for 3D animation and mesh export from a 3D program.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I will take a look at that.  I was trying to find a decent pipeline for Three.js animated characters from Maya.  2017 and 3D formats are still a mess.  I guess adding one more wouldn't hurt :P.

Answer (score 0):

None of the JSON formats for ThreeJS support keyframe or bone data I understand.  Right now I believe on Collada and possibly the MD* file types can be imported into ThreeJS directly with bone and keyframe data.